# How to hook up to click/change event on tzCheckbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this tzCheckbox,

```
<input type="checkbox" data-on="ON" data-off="OFF"/>
```

In the html output, I see this checkbox is hidden and a span element takes its place. I want to hook up to the click event of the checkbox. How can I do that? I tried these two, the functions were not being triggered.

```
$('input:checkbox').bind('click',function(e)...
$('input:checkbox').bind('change',function(e)...
```

Tried this, this didn't work either.

```
$('.tzCheckBox').bind('click',...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

depending on the version of jquery try using .on instead. also if the checkbox is dynamically added you may need a delegate selector. bind is for jquery 1.7 and lower. on is for 1.8 and up.

```
$('input:checkbox').on("change", function(){
        alert("box has changed");
    });

$("form").on("change", "input:checkbox", function(){
    alert("box has changed");
});
```